# Как манипулировать изображением внутри элемента SVG?

Tags: svg, изображения, viewbox

Проблема: не могу разобраться в правилах поведения изображения, являющегося заливкой svg-элемента с тегом `<path>`.
Я уже не знаю какие ключевые слова надо вбить в поисковик, чтобы найти соответствующую документацию, мучаюсь три месяца.
В тех статьях, что удается нагуглить описываются только примеры с `<rect>` и везде указано, что высота и ширина изображения задаются в теге `<pattern>`, но пытаясь их изменить в своем коде изображение только двигается по координатам, а иногда не двигается, или обрезается.
Каким-то чудом все-таки увеличивается иногда, но попытки воспроизвести то же самое с другим элементом заканчиваются провалом, так как изображения для фона не всегда удается подобрать одинакового разрешения.
Пытался убирать и viewbox и свойства ширины и высоты из тегов по очереди.  Собственно сам код:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 330">
    <defs>
        <style>.a{fill:url(#test);stroke:#000;stroke-width:10px;}</style>
        <pattern id="test" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100%" height="100%" 
    viewbox="0 0 360 330">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4b/d7/fb/4bd7fb27221140b0c023e8fbec2b1285.jpg" 
    width="100%" height="100%" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>

    <path class="a" d="M198.5,85.5c-65.45,5.64-120.09,40.55-136,90-15.1,46.95,9.53,92,27,124,16.24,29.73,37.8,69.19,81,84,37.9,13,71-.35,132-25,64.15-25.9,103-41.61,113-76,9.75-33.68-19.45-46.52-27-115-6.07-55,9.88-72.84-3-91C371.05,56.13,327.2,45.06,198.5,85.5Z"/>
</svg>
```

Никак не могу понять, какой из width и height за какое конкретно преобразование изображения отвечает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как друг от друга зависят viewbox в тегах `<svg>` и `<pattern>`, и как от них зависит каждый из значений width и height в тегах `<pattern>` и `<image>`?
И есть ли смысл манипулировать размером используемого для заливки изображения?
Может у меня имеются лишние свойства?
Какое свойство отвечает за увеличение этого изображения, не увеличивая размер самого svg-элемента, в конце концов?
Координаты (х,у) специально не задавал, так как они и без документации понятно чем управляют.

Comment: я вкладку не закрываю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас несколько объектов и факторов, которые отвечают за размеры и масштабирование элементов SVG.

Нужно разделить ваш код на несколько простых частей и разобраться, как получить необходимые размеры и отчего зависит масштабирование.

Выбранное изображение имеет размеры `1920 х 1080px`

1. В  SVG  размеры, показанного изображения, зависят от соотношения:
   Если **`viewport / viewBox = 1`**,
   то при равенстве размеров, изображение выводится в том же масштабе, как нарисовано.
   `viewport` это `width` и `height` в шапке SVG

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0qca.jpg" 
    width="100%" height="100%" />
    
</svg>
```

2. При **`viewport / viewBox < 1`** Изображение уменьшается

Например, для уменьшения изображения в два раза, уменьшаем `width="960"` и `height="540"` в два раза, при тех же значениях `viewBox="0 0 1920 1080"`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="960" height="540" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0qca.jpg" 
    width="100%" height="100%" />
</
```

То есть два пикселя, взятые во `viewBox`, уплотняются в один пиксель `vireport` за счёт этого происходит уменьшение размера

3. При **`viewport / viewBox > 1`** происходит увеличение размера.
   В этом случае, как раз возможна [обрезка изображения](http://svg-art.ru/?p=5#m_2_1)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1920" height="1080" viewBox="0 0 960 540">
    <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0qca.jpg"/>
 </svg>
```

`viewBox="0 0 960 540"` стал в два раза меньше, то есть захватил только половину изображения, остальное обрезалось, но в оставшейся части один пиксель viewBox растягивается до двух пикселей viewport, поэтому изображение увеличивается.

Другими словами viewport (это `width, height` SVG> это своеобразное окно, в котором мы видим результат вычислений масштабирования.

**Для простоты усвоения, запомните простое правило: у viewBox всё наоборот:**

1. при увеличении viewBox изображение уменьшается
2. при уменьшении viewBox изображение увеличивается

Более подробные объяснения с примерами можно посмотреть [здесь](http://svg-art.ru/?p=5)

### Практические советы

На первых шагах освоения SVG избегайте вложенных viewBox, так как при этом происходит многократное масштабирование и позиционирование, в которых легко запутаться.

Речь идет в этом конкретном примере о viewBox в pattern. Лучше указать фиксированные размеры.

Паттерн можно представить, как какую-то площадь, имеющие размеры, допустим 1920х1080px, которую нужно заполнить плитками допустим 100х100 px 
Заполнение идет порядно. Итого должно быть 19 плиток по горизонтали и 10 целых плиток по вертикали.   Подробнее [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875)

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1900 1080">
    <defs>
      <!--Одна плитка 100х100px в паттерне -->
     <pattern id="test" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100px" height="100px">
            <rect width="100" height="100" fill="none" stroke="red" />
        </pattern>
    </defs> 
    <!-- Заполняемый плитками объект-->
   <rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" style="fill:url(#test)" />
    
</svg>
```

Вместо нескольких плиток вы можете добавить в паттерн фотообои, то есть изображение.
Необходимо, чтобы размеры паттерна и картинки совпадали.

```css
.a {
fill:url(#test);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1900 1080">
    <defs>
         <pattern id="test" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1900px" height="1080px">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0qca.jpg" width="1900" height="1080"  />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
   <rect class="a"  width="100%" height="100%" rx="3%" />
    
</svg>
```

Как видно, изображение получилось респонсивно.

Теперь вместо прямоугольника вы можете создать любой криволиниейный объект и заполнить его паттерном `fill:url(#test);`

```css
.a{
 fill:url(#test);
 stroke:#000;
 stroke-width:10px;
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1900 1080">
    <defs>
         <pattern id="test" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1900px" height="1080px">
            <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0qca.jpg" width="1900" height="1080"  />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
   
    <path  class="a" d="M198.5,85.5c-65.45,5.64-120.09,40.55-136,90-15.1,46.95,9.53,92,27,124,16.24,29.73,37.8,69.19,81,84,37.9,13,71-.35,132-25,64.15-25.9,103-41.61,113-76,9.75-33.68-19.45-46.52-27-115-6.07-55,9.88-72.84-3-91C371.05,56.13,327.2,45.06,198.5,85.5Z"/>
</svg>
```

Теперь размер вырезанного изображения зависит от размеров кривой (path class="a")

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: В теории все было предельно ясно объяснено, поэтому галочку поставил. С этими знаниями сейчас попрактиковался и все встало на свои места. Плюс конечно поставил, просто подзабыл. Еще раз большое спасибо!